# How we can compare the drawing on a canvas with predefined image in Android?

Tags: android, xml, canvas, drawing

I am working on a project in developing an android app. I need to let the user draw on a predefined dashed-line image and show the percentage of the resulted drawing compare with the dashed-line image.
For example, a dashed-line "A", user fully draw overlay on the dashed-line "A", a completion of 100% will be shown.

Comment: What approaches have you tried and what problems did you run into ?

Comment: So, what's the question here? I see only description of the task.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I first thought was thinking about image comparing, but that does not really fulfil the requirement of overlay completion.

Comment: @vyegorov, the question is as the title. how do i compare the drawings?

Comment: @Soo are able to make this succesfully i am stucking on same as try to  make alphabet practise can u help me

Comment: How may I help you, @Khan ? I also new in the world of android. If you need help, maybe you can email me. I will pass the knowledge as others passed to me.

Comment: i am trying to make alphabet learnig practise as given Alphabet A and draw on it but not get properway i think u have worked on that so provide me some guidance @Soo

Comment: what problem you met ? I can't help you when i don't have any idea where you stuck.

Comment: Please consider to post answer if you were successful to implement it. It will help many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alpha masking. I will use your example and explain further.

The general idea is to insert a hidden mask which is basically an image with a predefined area that counts as a correct trace. You define that area using a color, for example the color red.

So now you have an image with a red A. You overlay that image on your dashed line and you make it transparent (alpha channels). When the user draws, all you have to do is check whether touch events are coming in the same position as red pixels of the hidden layer. If they are, that means that the user is tracing the line.

If you do not want to mess around with alpha channels you could be creative and do it in a different way. If I was in your place I would just create a normal image (no alpha channels needed) it could even be in grayscale (which would even be more memory efficient) and draw the different masks on it.

e.g. 
I want the user to trace over 2 letters: an A and a B. I open up any basic image editing software. Create a grayscale image that has the exact same size as the area in which touchevents should be detected. Draw a letter A with color value 100 (gray) and then draw a letter B with color value 50 (darker gray). Save the image.

In the application you just load up that image and keep it in memory as a 2d Array. Then you can use the [onTouchevent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) callback to get the touchevent positions. So, for example if the user touches the screen at postion (120,240) all you have to do is check the value at the image array you loaded earlier on at position [120][240]. If the value at that position is 100 that means the user is tracing over the letter A, if the value is 50 then the user is tracing over the letter B. Other values mean that the user is not tracing correctly.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for the idea. I think i should start working on that way. Any samples can I refer to ?

Comment: I don't really now of any specific sample, but it shouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: Since i am new to this field, it may be tough for me. 
How do I create the transparent alpha mask?
and, how do I check the touch events on the same position ?

Comment: I answered your question in my original post because there is no space here

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, the basic idea somehow i can understand it. But to implement it into code, i just get stuck. I think maybe it is a bit too much for me to ask that, but can you show me a basic code about that ? Especially the load into 2d array and check the value of the image array. Extremely thank you for spending your precious time in answering my questions so far. Gratitude.

Comment: I tried to use the following code in loading bitmap into 2d array.
`$`    int origPixel = 0;
    int []arr = new  int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
    int color = 0;
    int k =0;
    for(int j=0;j<bitmap.getHeight();j++){
    for(int i=0;i<bitmap.getWidth();i++, k++){
    origPixel= bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
    }
    }
`$`
It took super long for the loading. How do I improve the loading ? or is there another way ?

Comment: Once again thx for your help. The speed of loading the bitmap into 2d array is acceptable when i apply to the hardware. I got 1 point still cant figure out how. I have the the ontouchevent to detect the position as u mention, but the ontouchevent just return single point pixel. I used (int) getX() and (int) getY(). Anyway can i improve that ?

Comment: @RSai i have to compare texview text to canvas draw text.can u please help me?